# mysql - execute SELECT query only when TABLE EXIST

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am working on a Joomla Module where images can be shown and be linked to a Joomla Article, Virtuemart product or an external link.

To have to option to select a Virtuemart Product, I added the following parameter to the module manifest xml:

```
<field 
                    name="image_1_product" 
                    type="sql" 
                    default="10"
                    query="SELECT #__virtuemart_products.virtuemart_product_id, #__virtuemart_products_en_gb.product_name
                        FROM #__virtuemart_products, #__virtuemart_products_en_gb
                        WHERE #__virtuemart_products.virtuemart_product_id = #__virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id
                        AND #__virtuemart_products.published = 1"
                    key_field="virtuemart_product_id"
                    value_field="product_name"
                    label="LABEL_PRODUCT" 
                    description="DESC_PRODUCT">
                </field>
```

This works just fine, when Virtuemart is installed. When Virtuemart is not installed, you get an error 'Unknown column' - which makes sense.

Because this is a Module Manifest Option, I can use only 1 query. Is there a way to run a query that checks if a table exists before it executes the select? Like:

```
IF EXISTS TABLE `table_a` (SELECT * FROM table_a)
```

### If so, can it return a row like:

### | id | value                |

### | 0  | Virtuemart not found |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid its not possible with just single database query.

The only workaround that I can think of is to create a parameter helper for your module and use an `addfieldpath` to your module `fieldset` tag. With this solution you can write an method to do the query and create the output, then you can check if the table exists or not before creating your parameter.

*for example:*

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_mymodule/elements/">
            <field name="image_1_product" type="product" default="10" label="LABEL_PRODUCT" description="DESC_PRODUCT"/>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

now in `/modules/mod_mymodule/elements/` create a PHP file named `product.php` and write your custom query and field descriptions as described in Joomla's documentation.

Joomla documentation is available for [Custom parameter types](http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_parameter_types) and [Creating custom template parameter types](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_custom_template_parameter_types)